# R Change from stardard UTC time zone to multiple local time zones

Tags: r, datetime, timezone, posixct

Let's say I have a df with a series of responses to a survey. Each response has a time stamp in UTC. I also happen to have the local time zone for each person that filled out the survey.

For example:

```
 df <-  data.frame(day = c("2018-12-06 15:40:29", "2018-12-06 15:25:28", 
"2018-12-06 15:25:28", "2018-12-06 14:09:09"), time_zone = c("EST", "PST", "CST", "EST"))

df$day <- as.POSIXct(df$day, tz = "UTC")
```

I want to have all these dates reflect the time it was locally, for the person taking the survey. So I have tried the following:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(time_start = format(day, tz = time_zone))
```

But I get  `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: invalid 'tz' value.`

I have also tried with a data frame that has time zones in GTM format

```
df<-  data.frame(day = c("2018-12-06 15:40:29", "2018-12-06 15:25:28", 
"2018-12-06 15:25:28", "2018-12-06 14:09:09"), 
time_zone = c("GMT-5", "GMT-6", "GMT-7", "GMT-8"))
```

Is there a way of changing a series of standardized times to the local time?

Comment: Two problems, I suspect: (1) none of the date/time functions with which I'm familiar take multiple values for `tz`, ergo the `invalid 'tz' value`; and (2) `"GMT-7"` is not recognized by R as a valid timezone, verified with `format(Sys.time(), tz="GMT-7")` versus `format(Sys.time(), tz="GMT")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple problems here:

1. `format` (and other time-related functions) only takes a length-1 argument for `tz`;
2. time zones recognized by R do not include the popular `"CST"`, `"PST"`, etc.

To fix the first, the use of `Map` or `mapply` will suffice.

The second requires a little more research, unfortunately. Zones like `"PST"` and such, though popular in at least the US if not other countries, are not valid time zone strings (ref: CCTZ, a C++ library for translating between time zones, [says so](https://github.com/google/cctz/blob/master/include/cctz/time_zone.h#L61)). Neither are `"GMT-7"`, et al, though the latter can be faked by [prepending with `Etc/`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database#Area), as in: `"Etc/GMT-7"`. Or you can go with the alternatives of `"America/New_York"` or `"US/Eastern"`.

```
df$time_zone <- c("US/Eastern", "US/Pacific", "US/Central", "US/Eastern")
df
#                   day  time_zone
# 1 2018-12-06 15:40:29 US/Eastern
# 2 2018-12-06 15:25:28 US/Pacific
# 3 2018-12-06 15:25:28 US/Central
# 4 2018-12-06 14:09:09 US/Eastern
mapply(format, df$day, tz = "GMT")
# [1] "2018-12-06 15:40:29" "2018-12-06 15:25:28" "2018-12-06 15:25:28"
# [4] "2018-12-06 14:09:09"
mapply(format, df$day, tz = df$time_zone)
# [1] "2018-12-06 10:40:29" "2018-12-06 07:25:28" "2018-12-06 09:25:28"
# [4] "2018-12-06 09:09:09"
```

All of the immediately-recognizable formats for R's time zones are found in a 594-element vector:

```
str(OlsonNames())
#  chr [1:592] "Africa/Abidjan" "Africa/Accra" "Africa/Addis_Ababa" ...
#  - attr(*, "Version")= chr "2018e"
set.seed(2)
sample(OlsonNames(), size=8)
# [1] "America/El_Salvador"  "Etc/GMT+8"            "Atlantic/Madeira"    
# [4] "America/Creston"      "Pacific/Port_Moresby" "Pacific/Ponape"      
# [7] "America/Atka"         "GB-Eire"             
grep("US/", OlsonNames(), value = TRUE)
#  [1] "US/Alaska"         "US/Aleutian"       "US/Arizona"       
#  [4] "US/Central"        "US/East-Indiana"   "US/Eastern"       
#  [7] "US/Hawaii"         "US/Indiana-Starke" "US/Michigan"      
# [10] "US/Mountain"       "US/Pacific"        "US/Pacific-New"   
# [13] "US/Samoa"
```

In this example, you'll see one of the alternatives you can use: `"Etc/GMT+8"`. Notice that `+` is to the *west* of the prime meridian, so

```
mapply(format, df$day, tz = "US/Eastern")
# [1] "2018-12-06 10:40:29" "2018-12-06 10:25:28" "2018-12-06 10:25:28"
# [4] "2018-12-06 09:09:09"
mapply(format, df$day, tz = "Etc/GMT+5")
# [1] "2018-12-06 10:40:29" "2018-12-06 10:25:28" "2018-12-06 10:25:28"
# [4] "2018-12-06 09:09:09"
```

Caveat emptor: using `"US/Eastern"` should take into account daylight savings where appropriate; `"Etc/GMT+5"` does not, I believe.

Comment: Thanks, this solved it. It runs pretty slow though. Is that expected?

Comment: Not surprising. Because `format` (and friends) do not allow vectorizing the `tz=` argument, we are calling `format` once for each row of the frame. Actually, there's a way that might be much faster: group the data. Are you using `dplyr` or `data.table`? If so, we can modify this method to call `format` once *per unique timezone*, which should improve performance significantly. (Even if you aren't using either of those packages, we can do it, though it is slightly less-easy to read.)

Comment: But it worked perfectly fast with my 4-row sample ;-)

Comment: If I don't get back to it, something like `by(df, df$time_zone, function(d) format(d$day, tz=d$time_zone[1]))` after ensuring all `time_zone` fields are legit.